# Deploy multiple web apps using IIS

Tags: http, iis, web-applications, playframework-2.0, port

I am in a situation.

We have a Windows Server 2012 on which a play application is running. This play application is listen to port 80(using built-in HTTP server). Any request sent to my server say, http://abc.testserver.com is picked up by play.

We have one more web application which is developed using php and html. This is hosted on the same server on port 81 using IIS.

So any request http://abc.testserver.com:81 will launch my php web app. But we are not comfortable to expose the port no (i.e. 81) to the users.

Is there any way we can have both the applications running on the same server without displaying the port number to the user? (say use different domain names)

Please help us with possible approach if there is any.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, read about setting IIS as a 'reverse proxy' it's technique you're looking for. Note I'm not familiar with Windows server, therefore not writing this as an answer. see here: http://serverfault.com/a/152411/118032

Comment: can you use different host name for 2nd application? like http://abc2.testserver.com?